# Asp.Net returning 404 status code, displays empty / blank page in mozilla firefox

Tags: asp.net-core, firefox

When I an returning 404 status code in Asp.Net Core API project.
It works fine with chrome but, shows blank page in mozilla firefox instead of 404 error page, like in other browsers.

Sample Code for my API is below:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("OpenBlobFile", Name = "url")]
public async Task<ActionResult> OpenBlobFile(string fileName, string folder)
{
    return new NotFoundObjectResult(null);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5M85.png)

Comment: Without details no one will be able to answer u. What is the context? What did u want to achieve? Was any JS involved... and so on. I think your question will be downvoted by other because of the way you put it.

Comment: @DA I want to achieve browser error 404 page, in mozilla firefox. JS does not exist in API project, I think.

Comment: Return to the usual 404 error page? What version of FF are you using, you can take a look at this question, it may be helpful to you:https://forums.asp.net/t/1384390.aspx?Returning+404+from+controller+displays+empty+page+in+firefox

Answer (score 2):

I got my answer from here: https://forums.asp.net/t/1384390.aspx?Returning+404+from+controller+displays+empty+page+in+firefox

Conclusion:
Firefox does not have a native error page, like in other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Chrome and IE behave normally and display the corresponding default error page, while Firefox believes it is best to display a blank page.

Therefore, in most cases, Firefox will not display a generic 404 error page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use these if you want just a 404 error

```
 return StatusCode(404);
 return new StatusCodeResult(404);
```

Any of these won't, as they add either the id or an object to the response's body

```
 return StatusCode(404, 123);
 return StatusCode(404, new { id = 123 });
 return new NotFoundObjectResult(123);
```

Comment: I want the browser to return its own 404 error page.